# Splash Screen not showing with Phonegap Build

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

The issue happens with Android. The Splash screen does not show up after I use Phonegap build to create the application. I am using cordova-plugin-splashscreen, but that is not helping

These two lines are at the bottom of the config.xml file. That's not helping:
`<icon src="icon.png" />`
`<gap:splash src="splash.png" />`

I looked inside the apk file, and the splash.png image only appears in /res/drawable-mdpi-v4/  It is not in /res/drawable, only the icon.png file is.

Comment: is the path right? you have the icons and splash on the root folder?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the path but the resolution. The image was too big. Once I made it smaller (800 x 400), it worked.